# Setting the time through a UWP written in c++/CX

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, c++-cx

We are running an "assigned access" app on our device that doesn't use a network connection. The product powers up and immediately runs our company's UWP app on Windows 10 build 1703.

This device is international and it is required to set the time and date based on the current region and local DST rules.

As UWP applications are sand-boxed by default, such system calls are not generally available. This app will never be placed in the store however, so is there any workaround possible that we can use to allow the time to be set given that we do not need to abide by store rules? (A "full-trust" UWP app? I understand this might be restricted to converted win32 apps)

Currently the time and date is read through the Windows::Globalization::Calendar methods, but this has no "setter" method (presumably due to the app restrictions)

Another possibility may be to launch a win32 application from the app that sets the time; perhaps passing the time and date as a command line parameter. Is this the best solution and will it actually work?
Can anything be added to the app manifest that might enable this functionality?

Not being able to set the date and time would be quite a restriction for our particular app as it makes use of timestamps etc.

Comment: There is something else to consider besides finding an API to set time, the app doesn't have the adequate privileges. For example, if you choose launching a desktop app from the UWP app, which can be done by using [FullTrustProcessLauncher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.fulltrustprocesslauncher#Windows_ApplicationModel_FullTrustProcessLauncher_LaunchFullTrustProcessForAppAsync_System_String_). You would receive error like "The requested operation requires elevation".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This app will never be placed in the store

You could think about using [Brokered Windows Runtime Components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/brokered-windows-runtime-components-for-side-loaded-windows-store-apps). This is made possible by allowing side-loaded Universal Windows Platform apps to interoperate with desktop processes outside of the app container.

This blog about [Cheat-Sheet for using Brokered Windows Runtime Components for side-loaded Windows Store apps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2014/04/14/cheat-sheet-for-using-brokered-windows-runtime-components-for-side-loaded-windows-store-apps/) also is for your details.

Here's a code sample for your reference: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Brokered-Windows-Runtime-9d64cada

Comment: Thanks - this seems to be the closest to what I imagined would be available. I haven't used this in the past, so I will have to experiment to see if it ultimately solves the issue. I will accept it as the answer. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are better off using WPF and then porting it to the store via the desktop bridge.

WPF is pretty much like uwp minus the sandbox, you can make a new wpf project on blend, and use the same xaml you used on the uwp app.

this will only work on desktops and surface hubs tho, so keep it mind.

ps: launching an win32 app from uwp is possible but it will also limit it to desktop only, so you see your better off using WPF in any case.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root

Comment: Many thanks for the suggested answer. In this case the application is large and already ported from pure C++ (it uses C++/CX at the ABI only). It is fine to restrict the execution to the desktop, but it would not be practical to rewrite in c# to access this single feature. I would prefer not to launch a win32 app to perform this task unless it is absolutely necessary!

Comment: @Keano  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1     there is this timedate structure that might help, then again it wont set the system time.